# Print the hash elements by grouping their values in Raku

Tags: hash, raku

I keep record of how many times a letter occur in a word e.g. 'embeddedss'

```
my %x := {e => 3, m => 1, b => 1, d => 3, s => 2};
```

I'd like to print the elements by grouping their values like this:

```
# e and d 3 times
# m and b 1 times
# s 2 times
```

How to do it practically i.e. without constructing loops (if there is any)?

*Optional* Before printing the hash, I'd like to convert and assing it to a temporary data structure such as `( <3 e d>, <1 m b>, <2 s> )` and then print it. What could be the most practical data structure and way to print it?

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the output format you'd like to produce.  When elements have the same value, do you want to group them and print them on a single line (the way you do with `# e and d 3 times`)?  Or do you want to print them on separate lines (the way you do with `m` and `b`)?  Or are you intentionally wanting to treat elements with a value of `1` differently from elements with other values?

Comment: @codesections Ops! You're correct. I've just edited the question.

Comment: `say %x.categorize(*.value).map({ .value».key.join(" ") ~ " " ~ .key ~ " times"}).join("\n")`  Have to run, but so I'll leave it to someone else to formulate into an answer / handle using "and"

Comment: @user0721090601 I've run it and it works :)

Comment: I hope you didn't write code to create a Hash for keeping track of the count of letters when you can just use `.Bag`. `'embeddedss'.comb.Bag`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `.categorize` as suggested in the comments, you can group them together based on the value.

```
%x.categorize(*.value)
```

This produces a Hash, with the keys being the value used for categorization, and the values being Pairs from your original Hash (`$x`). This can be looped over using `for` or `.map`. The letters you originally counted are the key of the Pairs, which can be neatly extracted using `.map`.

```
for %x.categorize(*.value) {
    say "{$_.value.map(*.key).join(' and ')} {$_.key} times";
}
```

Optionally, you can also sort the List by occurrences using `.sort`. This will sort the lowest number first, but adding a simple `.reverse` will make the highest value come first.

```
for %x.categorize(*.value).sort.reverse {
     say "{$_.value.map(*.key).join(' and ')} {$_.key} times";
}
```